# Find in set comma escaped

Tags: mysql, sql

I need to know two things: how should I store a list that contains "comma" and how can I get a value from this list (using `FIND_IN_SET()`, for instance).

Basically I created a `TINYTEXT` column that currently has three possible values (note: I can't use `SET` type here)​​: `ABC`, `123` and `A,9`. I need to know how I can use the `FIND_IN_SET()` function in order to find individually an item in this list.

**First Question**: how should I store this information in the cell when, for example, I have options `123` and `A,9` activated?

If I consider a comma escape to `A,9`, would be stored like this: `123,A\,9`. Which would not be a problem and, in fact, I would like it to work anyway.

**Second Question**: finally, how to verify that the information `A,9` in the list? I could do: `FIND_IN_SET("A\,9", "123,A\,9")`. However, this does not work.

**My trials**:

```
SELECT FIND_IN_SET("2,3", "1,2\,3"); // => 0
SELECT FIND_IN_SET("2\,3", "1,2\,3"); // => 0
SELECT FIND_IN_SET("2\,3", "1,2\\,3"); // => 0
SELECT FIND_IN_SET("2\\,3", "1,2\\,3"); // => 0
SELECT FIND_IN_SET("2\\,3", "1,2\,3"); // => 0
```

Comment: Instead of using `\,`, why not use another delimiter, e.g. `A|9`?

Comment: How should you do it. Normalise. As soon as you need to use Find_In_Set, or indeed query against any part of a multi-value field, get rid of it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to find a comma with mysql find\_in\_set](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35759568/how-to-find-a-comma-with-mysql-find-in-set)

Comment: The 2016 question is the duplicated, not mine (that is from 2014). But I agree that it treats the same question.

Comment: In the case of "Media, inc." as a single string, how does it work?

FIND_IN_SET("abc","Media, inc.")

Could someone explain?

Comment: @DavidRodrigues just wondering did u find a solution?