# how to find a comma with mysql find_in_set

Tags: mysql

is it possible to find a `commma` with `find_in_set`?

I tried:

```
select find_in_set('\,', '\,');
```

my use case is:

```
where find_in_set(r.tag, vfilterList)
```

here, vfilterList is a comma separated list provided as input to a stored procedure - and r.tag is the tag string in the table. (So I want to filter to only rows that have a tag that's in the vfilterList). However some tag strings have commas in them. (in vfilterList the commas in tags would be escaped?).

Something tells me i'm doing it wrong?

Comment: I don't think it's possible.

Comment: Just one of the many reasons not to use comma-separated lists in table columns.

Comment: the comma separated list comes from another system and is an input variable to the stored procedure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it isn't possible.

The documentation specifically points out that this doesn't work.

> This function does not work properly if the first argument contains a comma (“,”) character.
>
> http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set

The function is designed to return the ordinal position of a substring, delimited by commas.  By definition, essentially, it would never find anything with a comma in it, since it's only considering the values between them.

Depending on what you're actually trying to accomplish, `INSTR()` or `SUBSTRING_INDEX()` might be useful.

Answer (score 0):

Ended up just replacing commas with pipes. (and doing the same for each tag within the filter list). It's reasonably accurate with false positives very unlikely for our use case.

```
where find_in_set(replace(r.tag,",","|"), vfilterList)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Robert! That saved my life. I almost killed my head tring to figure out how to fix it. :)